# Aero Wizard not displaying title/description correctly in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, wizard, qt-designer

I am currently making a Project in Qt (using designer) that uses an Wizard with the Aero Wizard style.

When I run my program, it shows the Wizard but the title is 1/3 down the wizard and the description is 2/3 down the wizard (can't do picture because of stupid rules). Is it something I am doing wrong, or a bug in Qt.

Additionally, any widgets placed in the wizard go below the description, often causing them to "overflow" outside the window.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. All I had to to was lay it out horizontally, then it displays properly!